# Comparing a Image to a Bitmap?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

Here's my code:

```
borderTop.BackgroundImage == Properties.Resources.buttonTopSelected
```

I need to see if the .BackgroundImage property is the same as the picture I added to resource. How may I compare these two images?

In code, one is a Image and one is a Bitmap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to post more of the code, I don't understand how your question relates to your code snippet.

Comment: @Lazarus: I'll edit my question to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the references so you can compare them later.  Something like:

```
    Bitmap top = Properties.Resources.buttonTopSelected;
    Bitmap bottom = Properties.Resources.buttonBottomSelected;
    ...
       borderTop.BackgroundImage = top;
    ...
       if (borderTop.BackgroundImage == top) {
           // etc..
       }
```

Don't forget to dispose them in the form's Dispose() method.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to store state in the BackgroundImage? Perhaps adding another property violates the DRY principle as state is effectively indicated by BackgroundImage. Hmm.... got me thinking now, still smells bad but that may just be me :)

Answer (score 0):

The comparison won't work as they are not the same object, this is comparing references not object properties. While you could compare the images pixel by pixel that's somewhat overkill, I'd probably suggest using some other way to store the button state either in an existing button property or by extending the button into your own class that has additional information (using composition or inheritance).

----- EDIT -----

You could add state to the Button through inheritance, i.e.:

```
public class MyButtonWithState : Button 
{
    public int ButtonState { get; set; }
}
```

You can then instantiate your buttons using MyButtonWithState rather than just button.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyButtonWithState NewButton = new MyButtonWithState();
    NewButton.Text = "My Test Button";
    NewButton.ButtonState = 3;
    this.Controls.Add(NewButton);
}
```

If you want this available at design time there's a bit more to do but this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: I gave you an upvote because I learned that it was comparing references and not the object itself. However I'm at a loss now on how to compare the images. How could I set the state of the button without comparing the images? I'd have to get the initial state from somewhere.

Comment: Regarding edit: Yeah I was thinking of something like that. It's a bit overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish though.

Comment: In comparison to a pixel-by-pixel comparison of the images (your only other option I believe) I think it's much, much lighter and quicker. You could make the ButtonState a string and store the name of the resource you've loaded as an alternative but I don't see a lot of benefit there. At the end of the day, you need to be comfortable with the code not I :)

Comment: Good point, I'll think a bit more and just bite the bullet. Since the images are only 20x20, I don't think it'll be that taxing, correct?

Comment: @Sergio Boombastic: I think @Hans Passant may have cracked it for you, it should work and wouldn't involve the full image compare.